# rendering two partials into one (rails 3), am I doing this right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the Public_Activity gem to display the list of actions being performed on the website. I already have a main feed on the homepage but I would also like to include all of the activities that are being tracked using that gem.

Here's what I am trying to do inside the controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
      @feed_posts = current_user.feed.without_review.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @feed_items = @feed_posts + @feed_activities 
    end
  end
```

Then in my view, this is how I'm trying to call it

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

the _feed_item.html being called above is

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
<br>

  <% if @feed_activities? %>
  <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> has posted
  <% else %>
  <div class ="gravatarhome"><%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %></div>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
      </span>
      <span class="textname">shared this</span><span class="timestamp"> <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <div class="FeedContent"><%= truncate(feed_item.content, :length=>150, :omission=>' ...(continued)') %>
<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title: feed_item.content %>

    <% end %><br>

  <% end %>
  </li>
```

However, I'm getting this error

```
    NameError in Static_pages#home

Showing C:/app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined local variable or method `activity' for #<#<Class:0x6ef3b98>:0x60d50d8>
```

anyone know if there's a better way to do this and where the activity variable needs to be defined to get this to work?

Update: here's my application_controller that uses the gem

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController
```

Answer (score 0):

The error have stated the problem, rails does not know which activity refer to.

Neither you have activity loaded in the controller, or it is associated to feed_item
Or not rails does not know which activity refer to

Answer (score 0):

activity is a variable that is not defined in this partial, so it will give error.
If you want to loop all activities via collection, then you have to pass variable as collection while rendering the partial and calling using partial name like this:

```
<%= link_to feed_item.owner.name, feed_item.owner if feed_item.owner %> has posted
```

Replace activity by feed_item in your partial. It will solve your problem.

Comment: now I'm getting undefined method `owner'... do you know where I need to define this?

Comment: first let me know, what you want to loop through and does it having any method named owner or association with owner.

Comment: Here, feed_item is an object by looping through @feed_items collection variable you have passed while rendering partial. And its not having any method or association named owner. So its giving error undefined method `owner'.

Comment: how can I fix this undefined method?

Comment: what is owner here... any model, method? You have to paste your model code also. And you have used feed_items = feed_posts + feed_activities . You can use this if both feed_posts and feed_activities are instances of same class.